# How to check the date is in US format in java

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

The user enters the date as follows:

20/05/2015

Now we know that in US format this date is invalid.
How do i check that in java?
In my code I get the date value from an excel sheet and currently this is how I'm processing it. The date read from the excel sheet is numerical. For example-3124.0 i.e., the no. of days passed since 1/1/1990. I am converting it into the format MM/dd/yyy:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
String s = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
```

format method of SimpleDateFormat takes in date as the parameter. hence cell.getDateCellValue() gives date type value which is passed to format method which converts it into string value.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
 String s = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
 System.out.println(s);   
 sdf.setLenient(false);
 Date d=    sdf.parse(s);
 System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

so now if the excel cell value is 12/08/2015

```
System.out.println(s);  // prints 12/08/2015

System.out.println(sdf.format(d)); //Prints 12/28/2015
```

don't understand.

Comment: Is the date stored in Excel as a String, or as a Date? And if it's a date, did excel perhaps automatically swap the formatting rules on the cell to be Worldwide rather than US formatted?

Comment: If a user enters a date such as `1/1/1` it could be in any one of six formats. How is software supposed to check what is in the users mind? For software to reliably determine a date format you will need to constrain the user input.

Comment: the date value from excel comes as date because of this code : 'cell.getDateCellValue());'

Answer (score 1):

If your date comes as a **string** you can try this regex:

```
    String date ="20/11/2015";  

    private static final String DATE_PATTERN =
        "(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";

    pattern = Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println("mateched");
    }else {
        System.out.println("not matched");
    }
```

If you have to do this more than once, make `pattern` static and compile it once (in constructor or a static block probably).

Answer (score 0):

After doing simple date format, validate it using the below code snippet.
Please play around with the regex if you need another date formats too.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    s = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());

    Pattern datePattern = Pattern
            .compile("^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$");
    Matcher matcher = datePattern.matcher(s);

    LOG.info("Valid Date:" + matcher.find());
```

Comment: thats fine. but if i need to print invalid date. For example. System.out.println("Invalid Date:" +); then what is the method?

Comment: why is this below code isn't printing invalid date even though there are 3 invlaid dates:  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY"); s= sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue()); Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$");
                  Matcher matcher = datePattern.matcher(s);
                  if(matcher.find()){
                  System.out.println("Valid Date:");
                  }
                  else{
                   System.out.println("invalidd date");
                  }`

Comment: matcher.find() will return true if it finds a substring in your date variable that matches the regex. You can use matcher.matches() if you want the variable to match precisely with your regex.

Comment: Also, please note that the above regex is not precise enough to check the entire date range. For. e.g. 11/31/2015 will still return a valid date.